# Logit probability with many option closely approximated by exponential probability

Tags: logistic, exponential-distribution, choice-modeling

In the paper "Firms and Labor Market Inequality: Evidence and Some Theory" by David Card and coauthors (2018) I find this passage, where a logit choice probability is closely approximated by exponential probability in the case of a large number of possible choices. Can anyone explain the algebra behind this approximation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The probability is given as a fraction; the term $\exp(\beta_s(\ln(w_{sj}-b_s)+a_{sj}))$ is the numerator, but is also a part of the sum in the denominator. For large amount of firms $J$, the numerator will not change much with changes of $\exp(\beta_s(\ln(w_{sj}-b_s)+a_{sj}))$. Therefore, we can approximate the denominator by a constant ($\frac{1}{\lambda_s}$), which roughly does not depend on $\exp(\beta_s(\ln(w_{sj}-b_s)+a_{sj}))$. This gives us the approximation of the whole formula as $\lambda_s \exp(\beta_s(\ln(w_{sj}-b_s)+a_{sj}))$